# Using SimpleJdbcInsert to insert into a table for which there is no bean.

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

My code:

```
SimpleJdbcInsert jdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dwDatasource).withTableName("DW.MYTABLE1");
Map<String,Object> parameters1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
parameters1.put("STRING2", "Entry2");
jdbcInsert.execute(parameters1);
```

I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate columns for table 'MYTABLE1' so an insert statement can't be generated
```

Note: If I was to set the same datasource on a jdbctemplate and do

```
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO DW.MYTABLE1 (STRING2) VALUES ('Entry2'));
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

when define the SimpleJdbcInsert ,Except the table name, You also need to specify the columns:

```
String[] columns = {"column1","column2"}

SimpleJdbcInsert jdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)
                .usingColumns(columns)
                .withTableName(table);
```